# Get the live position of a moving div?

Tags: jquery, position, coordinates

I would like to know if there's a way to get the live position of a div using either `.position()` or `.offset()`?

Here's my js code

```
var div = $('.btn').position();

$( ".live-position" ).text( "left: " + div.left + ", top: " + div.top ); // Get position of $('.btn)
```

but this only works on reload, the coordinations are not changing when I move a div with jquery

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KrQaOd)

Comment: You can get position in `setInterval()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you please guide me on how should i do that? I'm still new to jquery/js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `setInterval` you can acheive that. Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).

Below is an example. [Updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GqQWpZ)

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var div = $('.btn').position();
  $(".live-position").text("left: " + div.left + ", top: " + div.top);
}, 100);

$('.btn').animate({
  'margin-left': '200px',
  'margin-top': '70px'
}, 3000)
```

```css
.btn {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 5em;
}
.live-position {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn">
  text
</div>

<div class="live-position"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It does work. The problem with your code is, that you set the position only on initialization. You could use setInterval to update your position every few milliseconds.

```
$('.btn').animate({ 'margin-left':'200px', 'margin-top':'70px'}, 3000)

setInterval(function(){
var div = $('.btn').offset();
$( ".live-position" ).text( "left: " + div.left + ", top: " + div.top );
}, 100);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rpgpp2mp/

By the way, i changed position to offset, because i think thats what you want.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
setInterval(function() {
  var div = $('.btn').position();

   $( ".live-position" ).text( "left: " + div.left + ", top: " + div.top );
}, 1000);
```

check div position every 1 second